# Train booking & cancelation system

Tags: python, oop

I'm having trouble solving "Train booking & cancelation system". Can someone help me break it down?

"I'm encountering an issue with my Python code that handles train seat assignment. The code works as intended for single seat bookings, but when multiple seats are requested, it sometimes generates duplicate seat numbers. If someone wants more than one seat it will give a random seat number then will simple do +1 for more seats, so passengers can sit together (Example: family). I'd appreciate guidance on how to resolve this."

[Output of seat booking section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSsKC.png)

"Experiencing another issue that handles seat cancellation. When I attempt to remove a specific number, say '1,' it doesn't just remove standalone instances but also removes the number from within other digits, like '10' or '11.' Could you please guide me on how to resolve this behavior and only remove individual occurrences of the target number?"

[Output of seat cancellation section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rWwJ.png)   [File before cancelling the seats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeYtd.png)   [File after cancelling seats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4lBT.png)

```
import random

class Train:

    @staticmethod
    def greet():
        print("************* Welcome To Eastern Railway **************")
        print("Two trains are available.\n1.Rajdhani Express.\n2.Duronto Express.")
        print("*******************************************************")

    def __init__(self, name, number, Total_Seats, fare):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.seats = Total_Seats
        self.fare = fare
        #self.list_of_seats = list(range(1, Total_Seats+1))

    def seatCount(self):
        with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
            SeatList = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
            emtSeat = self.seats - len(SeatList)  
            print(f"Seat Available: {emtSeat}\n************************************")
        
    def getInfo(self):
        print(f"Train is {self.name} (No.{self.number}).\nTotal Seats: {self.seats}.\nSeat Fare: Rs.{self. fare}")
        print("************************************")
    
    def bookSeats(self):
        i = 1
        if (a1.lower()=="y"):
            A = int(input("How many seats do you want to book? ",))
            with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                SeatList = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                emtSeat = self.seats - len(SeatList)

            if(emtSeat<A):
                print("Sorry, the train has fewer seats!")
            elif(emtSeat>=A):
                #with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                 #   lines = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                print(f"Your {A} seat / seats is / are booked\nYour total fare: Rs.{self.fare*A}")
                #num = random.randint(1, Total_Seats)
                if (A == 1):
                    #with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                     #   lines = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                    while (0<A):
                        num = random.randint(1, Total_Seats)
                        if num not in SeatList:
                            with open(f'{j}.txt', 'a') as f:
                                f.write(f"\n{num}")
                                print("Your seat number is:",num)
                                A = A - 1 
                        elif num in SeatList:
                            pass

                elif (A!=1):
                    #with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                     #   lines = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                    print("Your seat numbers are:")
                    while (0<A):
                        num = random.randint(1, Total_Seats)
                        if num not in SeatList:
                            with open(f'{j}.txt', 'a') as f:
                                f.write(f"\n{num}")
                                print(f"{num}\t",end="") 
                                A = A-1
                                while (0<A):
                                    num = num + i
                                    with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                                        SeatList = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                                    if num not in SeatList:
                                        if (0<num<=Total_Seats):
                                            with open(f'{j}.txt', 'a') as f:
                                                f.write(f"\n{num}")
                                                print(f"{num}\t", end="")
                                                i = i+1
                                                A = A-1
                                        else:
                                            break
                                        
                                    elif num in SeatList:
                                        pass
                                #A = A - 1
                        elif num in SeatList:
                            pass
                    self.seats = self.seats - A
                    print("\n************************************")
                else:
                    print("Sorry the train is full!")
            elif(a1.lower()=="n"):
                pass
            else:
                print("You have entered a wrong input.")

    def cancelSeats(self):
        c = ""
        if (a2.lower()=="y"):
            B = int(input("How many seats do you want to cancel? ",)) 
            print(f"Your {B} seat / seats is / are canceled.\nYour total refund: Rs.{self.fare * B}.")
            if(self.seats<B):
                print("You entered wrong!")
            elif(self.seats>B):
                while (0<B):
                    with open(f'{j}.txt', 'r') as f:
                        SeatList = [int(line) for line in f.read().split()]
                    _B = int(input("Write seat number: ",))
                    
                    if _B in SeatList:
                        _B = str(_B)
                        with open(f'{j}.txt') as f:
                            SL = f.read()
                        SL = SL.replace(_B,c)
                        with open(f'{j}.txt', 'w') as f:           
                            f.write(SL)
                            print(f"Your seat No.{_B} is successfully cancelled")
                        B = B - 1
                    
                    else:
                        print(f"Your seat No.{_B} wasn't booked or doeasn't exist")

                print("************************************")
                #Train.getInfo(j)
            else:
                print("Sorry the train is full!")
        elif(a2.lower()=="n"):
            pass
        else:
            print("You have entered a wrong input.")

    @staticmethod
    def farewell():
        print("*******************************************************")
        print("***** Thank You For your visit To Eastern Railway *****")
        print("*******************************************************")


Rajdhani =  Train("Rajdhani Express", 10472, 10, 1000)
Duronto =  Train("Duronto Express" , 10437 , 20, 850)
Train.greet()

Train.getInfo(Rajdhani)
Train.getInfo(Duronto)

print("Which thain do you want to book or cancel?")
a = input("1. Press '1' for 'Rajdhani Express'.\n2. Press '2' for 'Duronto Express'.\n3. Press '0' to 'Exit'.\nPress: ")
print("************************************")

if (a == "1"):
    
    Total_Seats = 10    
    j = "Rajdhani"
   
    a1 = input("Do you want to book seat / seats?(Y/N): ",)
    a2 = input("Do you want to cancel seat / seats?(Y/N): ",)

    Train.seatCount(Rajdhani)
    Train.bookSeats(Rajdhani)
    Train.cancelSeats(Rajdhani)
    Train.getInfo(Rajdhani)

elif (a == "2"):

    Total_Seats = 20
    j = "Duronto"

    a1 = input("Do you want to book seat / seats?(Y/N): ",)
    a2 = input("Do you want to cancel seat / seats?(Y/N): ",)

    Train.bookSeats(Duronto)
    Train.cancelSeats(Duronto)
    Train.getInfo(Duronto)

elif (a == "0"):
    pass

else:
    print("You have entered a wrong input")

Train.farewell()
```

What I've tried:

- Implemented functions for booking, cancellation, and seat assignment, utilizing recursion where applicable.
- Utilized OOP principles to model train, passenger, and booking objects.
- Managed seat availability and booking data using file I/O operations.

Expected behavior:

- Booking a seat should successfully assign a unique seat number, storing booking details in the file.
- Cancellation should accurately remove the booking and update seat availability.
- Seat assignments should avoid duplicates and respect passenger groupings when possible.

Comment: Looks like you may be struggling to understand OOP principles. For example *Train.getInfo(Rajdhani)* should be *Rajdhani.getInfo()*

Comment: Both works same for me. But can explain more please.